# Generate MD5 HASH BETWEEN T-SQL and Python for Unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, t-sql, hash, collation

I have a Unicode string that I want to hash using 2 different tools, Python and T-SQL:
I have tried the following functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[FUNC_HASH] (@INPUT VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(36)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(36);
    SET @RESULT = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),HASHBYTES('MD5',@INPUT),1);

    RETURN SUBSTRING(@RESULT,3,34)
    END
GO

SELECT dbo.[FUNC_HASH]('HĐTID123')
```

---

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.[FUNC_HASH] (@INPUT NVARCHAR(100)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(36)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT NVARCHAR(36);
    SET @RESULT = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),HASHBYTES('MD5',@INPUT),1);

    RETURN SUBSTRING(@RESULT,3,34)
    END
GO

SELECT dbo.[FUNC_HASH](N'HĐTID123')
```

---

```
import hashlib

def hash_coverter(source_str):
    result =  str(hashlib.md5(str(source_str).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()).upper()
    return result
hash_coverter("HĐTID123")
```

When testing with non-Unicode string, for example, 'TID123'
They both return the same answer : '2BDD0FE0AEA9FBC5C27A75085FB14388'
But when I insert a Unicode string, for example, 'HĐTID123' they will return a different set of results.

SQL(VARCHAR) : 'FE0E48AA12DF0075C8E2846796B44F10'

SQL(NVARCHAR) : 'C2A503D87D5EEF7340EDF6EC51DD2C47'

Python: 'CE88EADF61D061E8929363169DB60EF8'

Is there any way I can rewrite these 2 functions to get the same result?

My current database Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS. Using the NVARCHAR in the T-SQL function won't help me at all.

Comment: How do you test the Unicode string with `@INPUT VARCHAR(100)`, not `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: Ị have tried to switch everything to NVARCHAR, but it won't worked...

Comment: Sorry, but "it won't worked" isn't much to go on. If you edit your question to include complete code samples with data and both the actual and expected results perhaps someone can help.

Comment: Show us the hex being fed to MD5() in each case.

Comment: Hi, I have edited to add the full code using in this question

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 appears to be the issue. SQL Server 2019 supports UTF-8 collation:

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Input VarChar(100) collate LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 );
insert into @Samples ( Input ) values ( N'HĐTID123' );

select Convert( NVarChar(100), HashBytes( 'MD5', Input ), 1 ) from @Samples;
```

returns `0xCE88EADF61D061E8929363169DB60EF8`.

There ought to be a method that doesn't involve creating a table to force the collation, but it's after my bedtime so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=640b7e5a35cc5e6b3fb69ae957dd2809) example.

Comment: Hi Habo thanks for answering, but unfortunately Im currently usign Azure Synapse which does not support UTF-8 Collation yet